# Values from dictionary to excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image: output saved in excel]

[image: Values saved as dictionary in each run. Below image shows how values are saved as list for each variable in run9]

[image: at run9, ACTB variable has value for every time step (first 17 time steps are shown)]

I have 134 nodes. Fourteen different analysis (run) has been performed. Each run has values saved as dictionary, for all the 134 nodes. Each node has values saved for 150 time steps (150 values for each node).For example, Run 1 is saved as dictionary (10 time steps) i.e. node A, (0,1,0,5,6, 7, 8, 1, 0,6) and node B, (1,2,3,4,5,7, 6, 8,9,1). Similarly Run 2 is saved as dictionary. I could export these values to an excel sheet, but the values are saved together as (0,1,0,5,6, 7, 8, 1, 0,6). I want only the first three values for each node to be exported to excel sheet in three separate columns (instead of all the 10 values)

How to export the individual values in each column from run 1 and run 2 and save it in a excel sheet?

Code, which saves an excel sheet with all values listed in one column:

```
run1, run2, run3, run4, run5, run6, run7, run8, run9, run10, run11, run12, run13, run14 = data # each run has 5 values for 2 variables
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
 df.to_excel("data.xlsx")
```

When I run this code, `df_1= df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Value 1', 'Value 3', 'Value 5']]]`

I got the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-8d2d90289161> in <module>()
----> 1 df_1= df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Value 1', 'Value 3', 'Value 5']]]

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1308 
   1309         if type(key) is tuple:
-> 1310             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1311         else:
   1312             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    794     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    795         try:
--> 796             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    797         except IndexingError:
    798             pass

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    920         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    921             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 922                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    923 
    924                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1470                     raise ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')
   1471 
-> 1472                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
   1473 
   1474             # nested tuple slicing

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis)
   1034     def _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis=0):
   1035         if self._should_validate_iterable(axis):
-> 1036             self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
   1037 
   1038         labels = self.obj._get_axis(axis)

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
   1390 
   1391             # TODO: don't check the entire key unless necessary
-> 1392             if len(key) and np.all(ax.get_indexer_for(key) < 0):
   1393 
   1394                 raise KeyError("None of [%s] are in the [%s]" %

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_indexer_for(self, target, **kwargs)
   2384         """ guaranteed return of an indexer even when non-unique """
   2385         if self.is_unique:
-> 2386             return self.get_indexer(target, **kwargs)
   2387         indexer, _ = self.get_indexer_non_unique(target, **kwargs)
   2388         return indexer

/home/MBIAL/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2284                                  'backfill or nearest reindexing')
   2285 
-> 2286             indexer = self._engine.get_indexer(target._values)
   2287 
   2288         return _ensure_platform_int(indexer)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer (pandas/index.c:6077)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.lookup (pandas/hashtable.c:14050)()

TypeError: unhashable type
```

Thank you

Priya

Comment: Please update your question for clarity. Two things primarily: 1) you say that you want to export value 1,3,6, from each column but your columns only have lists with 5 values and 2) the title of your question should summarise your problem, as it stands now it is too broad. In essence you want to first split a column containing a list into multiple columns and after that choose specific columns to export to excel. This is two different problems.

Comment: Do you try my solution? If yes, there is some problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then filter `MultiIndex` in columns by [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
#python 3.6 +
f = lambda x: f'Value {x + 1}'
#python bellow 3.6
#f = lambda x: 'Value {}'.format(x + 1)
d = {x: pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist(), index=df.index).rename(columns=f) 
        for x in df.columns}
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)

df = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Value 1','Value 3','Value 5']]]
print (df)
            A                       B                
      Value 1 Value 3 Value 5 Value 1 Value 3 Value 5
Run 1       0       0       6       1       3       5
Run 2       0       0       1       1       3       0

df.to_excel(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

1. Split your list of values in a column to multiple columns by this:

   `df[['Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5','Value6']] = pd.DataFrame(df.A.values.tolist(), index= df.index)`
2. Select the columns you want:

   `df = df[['Value1','Value3','Value6']]`
3. Write to csv

   `import pandas as pd`

   `df.to_csv("Output.csv")`

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal. Thanks. I tried your code, but still I couldn't save each value in separate column. Please find the code, which I have used in the above question.

Comment: Good it solved your problem but my code and your code looks similar!!

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal. No I tried your code, which I have posted in the above question. It did not work for me. I am still looking for answers

Comment: What is the excat error or problem my code is causing?

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal. The code did not throw any error as well I did not get any excel sheet saved. But when I used the modified code (please see the above question), I get an excel sheet but with list of all the 5 values saved in one column, instead of 5 columns. As well as, I don't know how to save only 3 values instead of all the 5 values

Comment: then before saving check what is in df? Also, try making new df at every step so you know where is the error and which part is exactly not working..

Comment: @ Rahul Agrawal. Please find the attached image of excel sheet. For 14 runs, each variable stores 150 values here. I can reach only this step, I don't know to proceed from here

Comment: so, I assume tthis is your raw excel!! Now read this excel to df by `pd.read_excel("name.xlsx, sheename =0)` and then column by column run the code. And then save back the df to new xlsx

Comment: Please find the modified code in the question. I tried as you suggested but still not working. Is there anything has to be included in the code?

Comment: @jezrael. I tried your code, like you have given it. Sorry, I don't know Python very well. Should I mention the name of the file anywhere in your code?

Comment: Still facing problems..I guess you are not doing good job in telling what is the excat problem you are facing..

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal. I have re-phrased the question again, to make it more clearer.

Comment: @ jezrael and Rahul Agarwal. Please find the edited question with screenshots included. Still looking for answer. Thank you

Comment: Priya..let me reiterate...there is an excel as shown where you have one column called ACTB in which you have 10 values. Out of these 10 values you want 3 values. And this has to be done for all the columns in the excel you posted!! Correct me if I am wrong in understanding the problem

Comment: yes, you are right. I want values to shown in separate column and want only first 3 values to be shown in separate column. Yes I want to do it for all the columns as well

Comment: Now.. Have you read this excel/csv to python by pandas.to_csv function? If yes, then does the pandas df looks exactly like your excel or not?

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal.  Yes in pandas dataframe, the data looked exactly the same as shown in excel sheet. Yes, I have read the data from python to csv function

Comment: Ok..so now in your df if you apply jezreal code...where and what error u get? I am going step by step and slow here..so we can finally fix your problem

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal. I included the code given by jezreal below the code to save df in excel. When I run the code, neither it throws up an error or saves an excel sheet

Comment: dont directly save, go step by step..after every step check if it is moving towards your solution...try `print(df)` after every step and check!! Don't directly check excel

Comment: Yes I could run jezreal code, but it throwed up an error, which I have posted in the question. But, an excel sheet was saved, only for the ACTB node and all the 150 values were shown in separate column  this time. But, I just need to save only value 1, value 75 and value 150 for all the 134 nodes

Comment: It threw an error bcoz I remember your earlier question had "Value1" etc. etc. as column names which are not now? So, you need to change the code according to the question you asked that time. Still if you a df of ACTB node with 150 columns , you just need to select the desired column as shown in "Step2" of my answer. To Run this code for all columns just use loop or apply function and you are good to go!!

Comment: @ Rahul Agarwal. Many Thanks. I could use the for loop and get values for all 134 variables. I don't have  heading for the values, just for understanding sake, I posted the order of values in which I were interested. Is there way to take only certain values?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184467/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-priya).

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have heading for values, I found the value location for the node I  was interested using the below code:

df_1= df_1.iloc[:, [Node 1]]

When you run this code, it gives the start and stop location of node 1. So I gave this line in the above code provided by jezrael and saved my results to excel sheet.

Replaced this below line in jezrael code with the above line:

df = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Value 1','Value 3','Value 5']]]

@jezrael and Rahul Agarwal Thank you for all the help